# javascript setTimeout not working in closing a window opened throug previous js line

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to close a popup window after 3 seconds using setTimeout, but it desn't wait at all, it just close it instantly.

Can you please help me to understand what am I missing?

```
let handle = window.open(link, '\_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left)

setTimeout(handle.close(), 3000);
```

Comment: please use `setTimeout(() => handle.close(), 3000);` as setTimeout expects a function definition to execute

Comment: Doesn't work either :-(